# Must a GraphQL field be a Query type to be mentioned in a query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, graphql, client-server

Say I have this `GraphQL` query:

```
query GetUser($user_id: Int) {
  user(user_id: $user_id) {
    name
    groups(user_id $user_id) {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

This query recieves user id, and returns:

1. user's name
2. names of all the groups this user belongs to

I know that `user` should be defined in the SDL like this:

```
type Query{
  user(user_id: Int): User
}
```

and that the server should define a resolver function named `user`.

But - can I be sure that `groups` field is defined the same way?

More specifically - can I se sure that referring `groups` in a query is possible, i.e. like this:

```
query Groups($user_id: Int) {
  groups(user_id: $user_id) {
    name
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes. A single client query can refer to multiple queries each of which requires it's own resolver. You could even throw a mutation in there if you wanted.

However you could also just enhance your `User` type to include a `groups` field. This would be cleaner from both a modeling and querying point of view.

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  groups: [Group]
}
```

Then your query could just be:

```
query GetUser($user_id: Int) {
  user(user_id: $user_id) {
    name
    groups {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

The `groups` resolver that is under the `User` type would get the user's id from the `parent` argument in the resolver.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I had a typo in my question... the fields ```user``` and ```groups``` are actually nested (see the first code snippet). Does it change your answer?

Comment: Not really - you wouldn't need to pass the `user_id` explicitly to the nested `groups` field in your original query because it will get the parent user automatically from the `parent` argument to the resolver.